# Swift Vapor: How to read a JSON file?

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm using Vapor, the server-side Swift 4 framework for creating web servers. I have a migration that I'd like to apply that reads in from a JSON file; however, most if not all Swift tutorials I see on this indicate using `Bundle`, which to my knowledge, isn't available when developing server-side swift applications, which means attempts like this don't work:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myFile", withExtension: "json") {
...
```

This begs the question, given a relative file path, how can I read in a file using server-side Swift?

Comment: Try using *Data(contentsOf: "URL TO FILE")* method and see if that will help

Comment: @kathayatnk Trying that, it seems to be wanting a path that's in the Build/Products/Debug directory, and there's nothing there that'd match that.

Comment: That I suspect you are running the code using xcode. Try with terminal It would give you the path to your project folder and then you can append the required path to resource

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Silly me. Vapor exposes a `DirectoryConfig` object from which you can retrieve the working directory of the application. To parse a file, it thus becomes:

```
let directory = DirectoryConfig.detect()
let configDir = "Sources/App/Configuration"

do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: directory.workDir)
        .appendingPathComponent(configDir, isDirectory: true)
        .appendingPathComponent("myFile.json", isDirectory: false))

    // continue processing

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: `app.directory.workingDirectory` can be used as of Vapor 4